# Using the .step command to step a parameter of a transistor model in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I read [this](http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-the-step-command-to-perform-repeated-analysis.html) document and I want to step the β parameter of a transistor for the below circuit(to see it bigger please left-click on the image below):

[image]

Here is the model of the transistor and BF is the β:

> .model MyBJT NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100 BF=100 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3
>   CJC=8E-12 CJE=25E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12 ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10
>   RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=30 Icrating=800m mfg=NXP)

Then in the above line I change BF to {BF}

And step BF as follows:

> .step param BF 10 500 50

and then

> .tran 1

But I'm not getting many plots just one.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it even possible what I'm trying to do? Is there a way?

Comment: You should read how step works, and that it replaces {var} by the value.

Comment: In this case the value is MyBJT. So it is not possible(¿)

Comment: If I remember correctly you need .step NPN MyBJT(Bf) 10 500 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jramsay42 is correct.

See the help to `.STEP`:

> .STEP -- Parameter Sweeps This command causes an analysis to be
>   repeatedly performed while stepping the temperature, a model
>   parameter, a global parameter, or an independent source. Steps may be
>   linear, logarithmic, or specified as a list of values.
>
> Example: .step oct v1 1 20 5
>
> Step independent voltage source V1 from 1 to 20 logarithmically with 5
>   points per octave.
>
> Example: .step I1 10u 100u 10u
>
> Step independent current source I1 from 10u to 100u in step increments
>   of 10u.
>
> Example: .step param RLOAD LIST 5 10 15
>
> Perform the simulation three times with global parameter Rload being
>   5, 10 and 15.
>
> **Example: .step NPN 2N2222(VAF) 50 100 25**
>
> **Step NPN model parameter VAF from 50 to 100 in steps of 25.**
>
> Example: .step temp -55 125 10
>
> Step the temperature from -55°C to 125°C in 10-degree step. Step
>   sweeps may be nested up to three levels deep.

Which works as you expect it. You also don't have to replace the value of your model by `{BF}` in that case, it will just overwrite the value of the model.